# Converting ArcMap Route Elements to KML?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml

I have used ArcMap to create bus routes with stops using the 'Find Route' tool.

I have saved my maps as MXD files and need to convert to KML.

I tried to convert to KML using the conversion tool but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Marybeth. I think I've solved the issue by saving map feature class as a layer and then converting layer to KML.  This seems to have worked and it shows up in Google Earth, however, the resolution is crummy and the layer doesn't scale as I zoom in on Google Earth.  I'm a beginner (if you couldn't already tell).....